# How to put data in logs using pattern layout log4j2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j2, pattern-layout

I am defining log4j2 configuration in **log4j2-spring.xml**. In this i am defining pattern layout as following:

```
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%d [%thread] [%-5level] 
               [Content-Id:%X{CID}] [SessionId:%X{sessionId}] 
 [CustomerId:%X{customerId}] [%c{1.}] - %msg%n" />
```

Now i want to put data dynamically in customer ID but I don't know how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the [log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html), put the customerId into the `ThreadContext`

```
ThreadContext.put("customerId", <your customerID>);
```

And the placeholder will be replaced by log4j2

Comment: great its working , just one doubt will it work well if i put this in controller where thousands of request are coming with different customer id